# EventListener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I'm a beginner with Javascript and I'm stuck at something. Here's the code:

```
const button = document.querySelector('button')

const popupWrapper = document.querySelector('.popup-wrapper')

const popBox = document.querySelector('.popup-box')

const close = document.querySelector('.popup-close')
```

---

Notice: the whole wrapper is displayed to none, and the .popup-box is inside if the .popup-wrapper div (in case you didn't include that already:D)

---

```
button.addEventListener('click', () =>{ 

  popupWrapper.style.display = 'block';

});

close.addEventListener('click', () => {

  popupWrapper.style.display = 'none';

});

popupWrapper.addEventListener('click', () => {

  popupWrapper.style.display = 'none';

});
```

What I want to do is whenever I click anywhere on the wrapper space around the `.popup-box` itself, the whole wrapper (with the box) gets displayed to none, but when I click on `.popup-box` itself nothing happens. What do I write?

Comment: Please be aware that you can put the code into a snippet to make it more readable. Click the `<>` symbol when editing.

Comment: `addEventListener` callback takes an event as its argument, so if you want to prevent event's propagation, you can use `(event) => event.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addEventListener callback takes an event as it's argument, so if you want to prevent event's propagation (`prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases`), you can use `(event) => event.stopPropagation();` like here:

```
popupBox.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

  event.stopPropagation();

});
```